# また恋愛中の相手の恋人に、本の話など仕掛けてはいけない。例えば遊園地に行って黙って恋人とジェット・コースターに乗って遊ぶことに比べたら、ずっと不毛なお喋りにすぎないからだ。

Tags: meaning

また恋愛中の相手の恋人に、本の話など仕掛けてはいけない。例えば遊園地に行って黙って恋人とジェット・コースターに乗って遊ぶことに比べたら、ずっと不毛なお喋りにすぎないからだ。

I cannot put my finger on what the 黙って means in this sentence fragment.
My interpretation: Also, while in love, your partner i.e. boyfriend/girlfriend you should not start talking about books.  For Example: at an amusement park, if you go with your lover and do not speak to them (黙って?) and go on a roller coaster and compare it to the book thingy at the beginning->completely there will be barren talk that will definitely happen.

Comment: ん？どっかで見たような、と思ったら・・・　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80828/9831

Comment: "at the beginning" と "that will definitely happen" は、どの部分を訳したものですか？

Comment: @Chocolate 凄く見覚えあるなーと思ってましたｗ

Comment: @Chocolate What does the ずっと不毛なお喋りにすぎないからだ mean, does it mean if you read the book, then its like not talking at the amusement center? or does it mean you will not speak to your partner in real life if you show them the book?

Comment: @naruto What does the ずっと不毛なお喋りにすぎないからだ mean, does it mean if you read the book, then its like not talking at the amusement center? or does it mean you will not speak to your partner in real life if you show them the book?

Comment: ずっと不毛なお喋りにすぎない means (本の話をするのは)ずっと不毛なお喋りにすぎない ("Talking about books will become nothing but fruitless chatter"). Please learn what is にすぎない.

Comment: @JimmyYang I already know what にすぎない means.  My problem is what is the に比べたら doing, what is it comparing what to what?   Comparing reading a book to ignoring your partner at an amusement part, they will be similar?  Fruitless talk leading nowhere.  You do not use COMPARE in English, so I am wondering what is the に比べたら meaning here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

黙って adverbially modifies （恋人とジェット・コースターに乗って）遊ぶ.
黙って means "silently" "without talking".

例えば...

> 黙ってご飯を食べる -- eat silently
> 黙って映画を観る -- watch a movie silently

It indicates how you do 「（恋人とジェット・コースターに乗って）遊ぶ」.

I think the 「黙って」 here contrasts with 「本の話を仕掛ける」(start talking about books):

「本の話を仕掛ける」 vs 「黙って(遊ぶ)」

So I think 「黙って」 here implies 「本の話を仕掛けないで / 本の話をしないで...」 ("without talking about books...").

Comment: Wait, so what your trying to tell me is that talking with your partner about a romance book is akin to going to an amusement park and riding the roller coaster with your partner silently?  What sense does it mean, what idea is it trying to get across, I do noT understand, HELP  !!!!!

Comment: この「黙って」は、コースターに乗っている最中は静かにしろと言っているわけではないと思います。「黙って寝ろ」「ここは黙って引き下がろう」とかと同様の「反論せず」「とやかく言わず」「いちいち深く考えず」みたいな意味かなと。

Comment: そうですねぇ。。「本の話を仕掛ける」vs「黙る(=本の話をしない)」の対比かな、と思いました。ちょっと付け加えますね。

Comment: @fynxgloire, Let me break down the sentence (so that you can get its structure)... 「黙って恋人とジェット・コースターに乗って遊ぶことに比べたら」="Compared with riding a roller coaster with your girlfriend without talking", 「omitted subject=本の話をすることは」="talking about books would be...",「ずっと不毛なお喋りにすぎない」="(...would be) only a far more fruitless chatter."

Answer (score 2):

The basic meaning of this type of 黙って～する is "to shut one's mouth (and ...)".

> 黙って寝ろ。
> Shut your mouth and go to bed!
> Stop complaining/chattering and go to bed already!
>
> <sup>(Not: "Be quiet while you're sleeping!")</sup>

In your context, 黙って～する implies "to stop worrying and just ～" or "to just do ～ without quibbling", "to do ～ anyway". It does not mean you have to keep silent while you're having fun on a roller coaster.

～に比べたら means "if/when compared with ～", and everything before this に is the thing that is compared with the chat about a book. [～に過ぎない](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AB%E9%81%8E%E3%81%8E%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-ni-suginai-meaning/) is "is no more than a ～", "is only/merely ～".

> 例えば遊園地に行って黙って恋人とジェット・コースターに乗って遊ぶことに比べたら、[本の話は]ずっと不毛なお喋りにすぎないからだ。
>
> It's because, if compared with, say, going to an amusement park and *just* (happily) enjoying a roller coaster ride with your girlfriend, [chatting about a book] is merely a far more fruitless idle talk.

Comment: @aguijonazo 所構わず本の話を吹っかける変な人が話題である場合は別ですが、常識的には遊園地まで来てわざわざ本の話をすることはない（特にコースターに乗る前には）ですしそんなの言わなくても当然ですので、この「黙って」を「本のことは黙って」と解釈するのは不自然だと思います。ここで敢えて「黙って」を使うからには「つべこべいわずに」「あーだこーだ考えず、とっとと」のような方向で解釈すべきだと感じます。